# How to monitor API (Flask) hosted in EC2

Tags: python-3.x, flask, amazon-ec2

I have deployed a flask application in an EC2 that returns a json when hitting a certain url (with certain parameters).

I want to monitor the usage of this API, and use a token to track usage by user.

Are there any tools that I can integrate, or should I code it from scratch?

In the latter case, is there a reference/article I can look up to? Any ideas are be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps https://pypi.org/project/prometheus-flask-exporter/ in combination with prometheus/alertmanager/grafana can help you? It allows custom metrics via decorators to track queries by token.

Greetings
Joachim

Comment: Seems like a great combination. Will implement accordingly and share the outcome. Thank you for your answer 